# Exception breakpoint stops in main.m for -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception

In my Xcode project i added an exception breakpoint to stop on throw. Since i got some problems with a `-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. But my code still stops at

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

I know that it means that somewhere in my code I'm setting a int value to a NSString, but i really don't know where that is, which means I'm getting nowhere. Cant find the root to the exception and i got so many lines of code that i can't link it here.

So anyone know another way to make Xcode break where the problem is and not break on the main.m's UIApplicationMainthe?

Thanks a lot for your time.

EDIT: heres where my thread breaks [image]

And this is where the exception breakpoint stops the code[image]

My call stack looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Turn on breakPoint allException at Breakpoint Navigator and check.

Comment: And how do i turn that on? shouldn't it alrdy be on when I've added the breakpoint?

Comment: did you guys read my post?^^ I've alrdy got an exception breakpoint

Comment: i asked cause thats what i described in my post that I've alrdy done. So since he asks me to do it I'm thinking he must mean that i've done it wrong or something

Comment: I've updated the post as you can see i got a working breakpoint

Comment: Try zombie: press "command+I" -> choose Zombies -> Run your application and see where it crashes.

Comment: You are in the breakpoint view. Switch to the thread view to see the actual call stack.

Comment: It is necessary to "continue" execution a couple of times after the exception breakpoint in order to get the complete error message. The error messages can't print until after the breakpoint.

Comment: what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: This specific exception is not helpful because it's happening in CoreAnimation. Maybe you could find the number in the register and recognize it but your best bet is to try isolating the problem to the code you think triggers it and share that.

Comment: Show us the call stack.

Comment: (Most likely you've passed an NSNumber where an NSString was expected.)

Comment: Updated my post with my call stack as requested.

Comment: User nmh, I've done a run now with zombies enabled like so: Project > Scheme > Edit Scheme… Click the Run item in the list on the left. Then click the Diagnostics tab on the right. Turn on the “Enable Zombie Objects” checkbox. Same result:(

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your suggestions, because of that I've now managed to narrow my code down to a MUCH smaller section. I've now been able to conclude that the error happens in one of 6 cell.label.text's.

Comment: The problem was as expected(and suggested by multiple ppl) that i was passing a NSNumber to a text field(NSString)

Answer (score 0):

Without code we can not able to help you but This error saying that your are measure length of `NSNumber` instead of `NSString`. Check it step by step *(by using break point)* where you are doing mistake such like that, [just sear on google there are so may answers.](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=-%5B__NSCFNumber+length%5D%3a+unrecognized+selector+sent+to+instance&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=NV17U_X9HejV8ge964DwAg)

Comment: Updated my post, you can now see where my code breaks in the thread. And where it throws the exception.

Comment: @user2408952 - Show us the call stack or exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps.

Move to "Breakpoint Navigator".

Click + symbol at bottom-left corner of navigator.

You should see this :

[image]

click on Add Exception Breakpoint

[image]

click on Done

[image]

and you click on done and after you run your porgramme and it will break where the problem is.

Comment: Yes that's what I've alrdy done. As i described in my post. So not it breaks at the same line where it (before the breakpoint exception) just throwed a sigabrt

Comment: @poyo It is necessary to "continue" execution a couple of times after the exception breakpoint in order to get the full error message. The error messages can't print until after the breakpoint.

Comment: Almost everybody misses this because it is counter-intuitive.